# Remove chain guard from bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

[image: picture of problem]

What tool do I need to remove the black plastic cup that is holding
the metal holder for my chain guard?

I can rotate the metal part but the cup is not moving.
While googling I could not find anyone that used the same mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splined retaining ring is standard for internal bearing cassette type bottom brackets.

You need a bottom bracket tool such as the [Park Tool BBT-32](https://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-bbt-32). Googling 'bottom bracket tool 20 tooth' will yield other options. You will also need a suitably  large wrench of course.

Be aware that the right hand ring is a left handed thread. You also need to remove the left hand ring first as the right hand ring is integral to the bottom bracket cartridge.

Check out [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBnYoYVTnlo) that shows how to remove the rings and bottom bracket cartridge.